# Property that changes in constructor or as property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, constructor

I am working with C# using the MVVM pattern. I have two WPF windows, each with a view model. Basically I need to pass a property of the main view model to the 'child' view model. At the minute, I do this by setting a private variable equal to the new view model in the main view model's constructor, and in doing so passing the property in the constructor of the child view model.

However, there is a dependency property linked to the property as it used as a binding for the selected item in a combobox. Therefore, it is likely to change after the child view model is initialized, but by passing the property in the constructor, the change is not made in my child view model.

So, is there anyway for me to pass the property into the constructor and have it change in the child view model when it does in the main view model? Or would I have to create a property in the child view model which is updated everytime the property in the main view model is set?

Hope that makes sense.

**Edit** Inside my main view model, I declare the following:

```
public readonly DependencyProperty CurrentDatabaseManagedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentDatabaseManaged", typeof(DatabaseInfo), typeof(MainViewModel));
public DatabaseInfo CurrentDatabaseManaged {
    get { return (DatabaseInfo)GetValue(CurrentDatabaseManagedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentDatabaseManagedProperty, value); }
}

public DatabaseInfo CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection {
    get { return CurrentDatabaseManaged; }
    set {
        if (CurrentDatabaseManaged != null &&
            (String.Equals(value.Name, CurrentDatabaseManaged.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) return;

            CurrentDatabaseManaged = (value.IsUsable ? value : dbm.ReadDatabase(value.FileName));
        }
}
```

Where `CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection` is the SelectedItem of the combobox. In the constructor of the main view model, I have the following:

```
_DatabaseVM = new ChildViewModel(CurrentDatabaseManaged);
```

And the constructor of `ChildViewModel` looks like this:

```
public ChildViewModel( DatabaseInfo SelectedDatabase)
  {
    if (SelectedDatabase != null)
         _SelectedDatabase = SelectedDatabase;
    }
  }
```

Basically I would like `_SelectedDatabase` to be updated whenever `CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection` is.

Comment: please make your question simpler.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi Please suggest how I could do this? I have included all the information that I think is needed. The last paragraph could be a stand alone conclusion though

Comment: @Andy a code sample would help clarify your question. What do your constructor, binding, and other relevant parts look like?

Comment: @TimS. Ok, I will just edit my code a little so that I can post it here. Please bare with me

Comment: I agree with @SeyedMortezaMousavi. In your fist paragraph, you are saying, you create child view model inside parent view model and passing an object to child view model's constructor, correct? In your second paragraph, where is this dependency property? in parent view or child view? You hope when the property changed from dp, it also affect the property inside child view model? I think some code will make it clearer.

Comment: Please see my edit. @BillZhang The answer to your questions, in order: Yes. In the main view model (although I'm not sure whether it's actually relevant now - in that I was getting confused about the dependency property). And yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to bind to the `CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection` property. The simplest way to simulate this is to add this to the setter of that property:

```
_DatabaseVM._SelectedDatabase = value;
```

To do it with actual bindings, you'd need to

1. make `ChildViewModel._SelectedDatabase` a dependency property,
2. make `MainViewModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and
3. call the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of `CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection`.
4. make `ChildViewModel` extend [`DependencyObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)
5. instead of just setting the property, set a binding, e.g.

   ```
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, _SelectedDatabaseProperty,
     new Binding("CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection") { Source = mainViewModel });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to do step 4 but there is no SetBinding method... How do I get it?

Comment: @Andy I've updated the answer (steps 4 and 5 changed), it should be doable now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the value later, after bindings are set up in the UI.

Use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) method to put off updating the property until later on.

```
public MyClass(object someValue)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        (Action)(() => Property = someValue),  // the cast may not be required
        DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);  // runs after everything is loaded
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the tip about `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. So essentially what you are saying is that if my child view model needs a property that updates independently of it, I'd need to create a property in the child view model and pass the property that updates in when it is needed?